# file.read() returns different length in 2.7 and 3.3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a binary file,

```
file = open(fname,"Ub")
len(file.read())
```

In Python 3.3, it returns 1279200 which is correct. In Python 2.7, it returns 1279106.

What does this happen? What are the possible reasons?

In 2.7, how to get 1279200 bytes?

Comment: Guess it have to do with how they interperate the new-lines. Try opening with `rb` as it should be more cross-platform-version ignorant towards formatting :)

Comment: `U`niversal newline mode only makes sense with text files (and is deprecated anyway, so don't use it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, `U` and `b` don't go together.

Python 3 follows [PEP-3116](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3116/) for I/O implementation. If you look at [open() implementation](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3116/#the-open-built-in-function), you'd notice that `b` uses `Buffered*` interfaces, while universal newlines are implemented in [TextIOWrapper](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3116/#text-i-o). So, passing `b` simply disables the code that supports universal newlines.

In fact, this implementation of `open()` even fails if you try to enable binary mode and universal newlines at the same time. However, this code doesn't support the `U` mode argument at all, just the explicit `newline` parameter.

Now, I don't know why `U` in the actual implementation doesn't trigger the error. Maybe it's just an omission, maybe it's intended for backwards compatibility.

Now, Python 2 has two I/O implementations. If you used, `io.open()`, you'd get the same behavior as Python 3. However, you are using legacy `open()` that goes through C implementation of [file type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects) (relevant code: [open()](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1492), [field setting](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Objects/fileobject.c#l163), [get_line()](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Objects/fileobject.c#l1407)), and this code has no explicit separation between binary and text file support. Therefore, the universal newline support is applied to binary files as well.

So, to sum up: you are trying to use two conflicting file modes. In Python 3, this should likely trigger an error but it doesn't for some reason. Instead, `b` is stronger than `U` and the latter doesn't work. In Python 2, the code had no clear split between binary and text files, and both `b` and `U` are respected, depending on the context.

---

A quick test:

```
$ printf '1\n2\r\n3\n\r4\r5' > f
$ ipython3.3
In [1]: open('f', 'Ub').read()
Out[1]: b'1\n2\r\n3\n\r4\r5'

$ ipython2.7
In [1]: import io

In [2]: io.open('f', 'Ub').read()
Out[2]: '1\n2\r\n3\n\r4\r5'

In [3]: open('f', 'Ub').read()
Out[3]: '1\n2\n3\n\n4\n5'
```

Comment: In Python 2 [the source code explicitly supports 'b' in universal newlines mode](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/fileobject.c#l283) i.e., `'Ub'` may go together.

Comment: That's what I meant. I guess I might have made it a little blurry…

Answer (score 0):

quoting from python documation:

> supplying 'U' opens the file as a text file, but lines may be
>   terminated by any of the following: the Unix end-of-line convention
>   '\n', the Macintosh convention '\r', or the Windows convention '\r\n'.
>   All of these external representations are seen as '\n' by the Python
>   program. If Python is built without universal newlines support a mode
>   with 'U' is the same as normal text mode. Note that file objects so
>   opened also have an attribute called newlines which has a value of
>   None (if no newlines have yet been seen), '\n', '\r', '\r\n', or a
>   tuple containing all the newline types seen.

I suggest you using 'rb'/'wb' mode, this works!

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 [`'U'` mode is ignored](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3e19634b396f/Lib/_pyio.py#l65):

> 'U' mode is deprecated and will raise an exception in future versions
>    of Python.  It has no effect in Python 3.  Use `newline` to control
>    universal newlines mode.

`'b'` opens a file in binary mode so `len(file.read())` returns number of bytes in the file (`os.path.getsize(filename)`).

In Python 2 `'U'` and `'b'` [can be combined](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/fileobject.c#l266). `'b'` sets [`f_binary` flag](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/fileobject.c#l140) (no effect on reading as far as I can see) and it is passed to [platform-specific `fopen()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/fileobject.c#l357) (no effect on Unix). `'U'` enables universal newlines mode (`\r`, `\r\n` are translated to `\n`). It may change number of read bytes if there are `\r\n` in the file.